# Shell scripting - cut all the strings of a specific keyword in a file

Tags: bash, shell, delimiter, cut

I'm trying to make a script that takes in a log file where each line consists of a name + >tab< + runtime (number), like this:

```
calloffice      14
name    15
other   16
CallOffice      18
```

What i want to do is to find all lines that match a given name and then add together the runtime numbers.

So i started with getting them to print out in the first place. But my script should be able to search for a keyword in the logg file and get all the different runtimes from ONLY that keyword, now I get the runtime from ALL the numbers instead of only the keywords runtime.

this is what i have done so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What is the event?"

FILE=$1

while read text
do
    if grep "$text" hendelse.txt; then

    $text | cut -f2 -d$'\t' hendelse.txt

else 
    echo "text not found"
fi
done
```

I know I'm not even near the finish line in the script, but my question was just how do I get the runtime numbers from the specific keyword?

Comment: Update your question to include a) the contents of an sample log file, and b) explain what you mean by `numbers and combine them` (eg, do you want to `add` the numbers together) and provide an example of the desired result (when applied to the sample log file contents)

Comment: You understood it, I want to add them together and the final result would be for instance:   CallOffice 14 + CallOffice 14 =      "CallOffice 28" <--- like that

Comment: OK, so add that to your question (so later people don't have to read through these comments to piece together the full picture); also, fwiw, you've accepted an answer that does not perform the desired addition

Comment: I just wanted that answer really, but if people wanted to add some input they could. But thanks for the notes I will consider this next time.

Comment: you do realize that the answer you accepted does not do what you want, right?  if you have 2 entries with `calloffice`, the accepted answer does not add the numbers together to provide a sum/total

Comment: No it doesn't, it just gives me the numbers I wanted. And that was my core problem. Now i'm trying to figure out how to do the rest, as a student I want to do it myself but I needed help with the syntax here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the original question and bits-n-pieces extracted from OP's comments:

- there may be more than one matching line in file
- for all matching lines, add together the runtimes
- need to use case-insensitive string matching

Example input file:

```
$ cat test.txt
calloffice      14
name    15
other   16
CallOffice      18
```

One possible `awk` solution:

```
BEGIN {total=0}
tolower($1)==str {total+=$2}
END {printf "total : %s\n",total}
```

- `BEGIN {total=0}` : initialize our total
- `tolower($1)==str` : lower case field #1 (allows for case-insensitive matching), and if equal to our input string `str` then ...
- `total+=$2` : increment our total by the amount in field #2

And the `awk` script in action when passing in a search string of 'calloffice':

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {total=0}
tolower($1)==str {total+=$2}
END {printf "%s total : %s\n",str,total}
' str="calloffice" test.txt

calloffice total : 32
```

Comment: I get a result of 0 though?

Comment: awk '
BEGIN {total=0}
tolower($1)==str {total+=$2}
END {printf "%s total : %s\n",str,total}
' str="$text" hendelse.txt

Comment: what is the value of `$text`? what's in `hendelse.txt`; add your answers to your original question so we (the community) know exactly what you're working with

Comment: I don't know how to do it properly yet i'm working on it. $text is the value of my "reader" as you can see in the original post. And hendelse.txt is the file Im reading from since i don't have a actuall log file to work with.

Comment: no, I mean ... what's the output of `echo $text`? and what's the output from `cat hendelse.txt`?  add these outputs to your question

Answer (score 2):

You should use awk with tab as separator (awk -F"\t")

Assuming you have all the runtimes and names in a file separated by a tab.

You should do something like this (in this case the keyword is calloffice):

```html
~$ cat test.txt 
calloffice 14
name 15
other 16

~$ grep calloffice test.txt 
calloffice 14

~$ grep calloffice test.txt |awk -F"\t" '{print $2}'
14
```

Your result is 14, which is the runtime of the given keyword. Notice is the result of calling print of the second parameter ($2).

Comment: If you're using `awk`, you don't need `grep`: `awk -F'\t' '$1 == "calloffice" {print $2}' test.txt`, or to pass the name as a parameter `awk -F'\t' -v name="calloffice" '$1 == name {print $2}' test.txt`

Comment: Yeah that worked perfectly, thank you so much. I don't understand the '{print $2}' but it worked!

Comment: The awk works like this, it will split any word/line using spaces by default, for example the line "this is an example" using awk '{print $1, $3}' will print "this an" because those words are the first and third words separated by one space. Check more here http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/awk-introduction-tutorial-7-awk-print-examples

Comment: wow that is incredible, so now i can just combine my given variables, perfect!